# Omnet++ 4.6 and Castalia 3.3 signal direction - directional antenna WSN

Tags: omnet++

I wanted to compare the energy consumption of directional vs omnidirectional antennas in WSN specifically. Couple of questions:

1-) How the direction of the incoming signal determined? In which parameter the nodes (both sender and receiver) can store it? simply I need to find out the signal's coming angle if possible. I guess there is sth in Castalia related to that.

2-) The coordinator node's coordinates should be specified, isn't it?

3-) Any tutorial on the Battery depletion models for Castalia?

4-) If I just accept/transmit signals from/to a certain direction (with higher gain) can this be regarded quick-dirty directional antenna? How can this be done?

5-) I need more examples on these, especially on 802.15.4 stuff.

Sorry just a beginner in Castalia...

Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

There is no directional signal propagation model in Castalia, so you can't use Castalia for your purposes. You could built that model for Castalia, but this is a huge task.

There is no connection between the directionality of signal (physical layer) and the MAC protocol used (MAC layer). I am not sure why you are asking about it.

The battery model is yet another topic (note: it's better not to ask multiple unrelated questions within a StackOverflow question). Castalia's battery depletion model is a the most simple one: linear depletion. Other people have built more advanced models but I am not sure they are publicly available.